# How to test DNS (or other parts) for overall internet speed slowness?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, vpn, dns, performance

I'm forced to use this somewhat unknown vpn called LetsVPN to access my favorite sites in China. However, I noticed my speed dropping from 300+ Mbps (without the vpn) to around 10 Mbps consistently.

After a lot of brute force testing, I realized LetsVPN was setting my DNS to `26.26.26.53`. So every time I overrode that DNS and set it to, say, `1.1.1.1`, then my internet speed became fast again.

How can I test LetsVPN's preferred DNS to see if that's the actual bottleneck to my overall internet speed slowness?

I'm on a Mac and I'm comfortable with Terminal/Linux commands.

Comment: you may want to check the GRC DNS Benchmark utility to see if the LetsVPN servers are listed. https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm